# What version of Translate API does Google Cloud PHP Translate use?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

I just started using Google Translate API with the PHP SDK provided here https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-translate, but I can't find out whether v2 or v3 of Translate API is being used.

In my Cloud Translation API quota dashboard, all requests are grouped as "v2 and v3 Characters". I'd like to know whether v2 or v3 is used, as v3 is free 0 - 500,000 characters (https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing).

e.g.

```
$result = $translate->translate('Hello world!', [
    'target' => 'fr'
]);
```

I'd like to know which version is being used, and whether I can set the version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment this library is using the v2 [as you can see in the github respository](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-translate/blob/master/src/Connection/Rest.php#L43)

Seems like you can't set the any version with this client library as documentation shows official clients avaible only to [Java, Python and Node](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries-v3) to v3beta. Maybe you can build your own client library using the [REST endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/)